# NHibernate cannot resolve property of one to one mapping when used in a filter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Ok I've *got* to be doing something really stupid, but I just can't see what it is.

I have the following query:

```
Recipes recipe = null;
var q = session.QueryOver<Recipes>(() => recipe)
   .Where(p => p.Metadata.SkillCommon)
   .Where(p => !p.Hidden);
```

The `Recipes` model has a property called `Metadata` which is a one-to-one mapping to the `RecipeMetadata` model.  In other words, every recipe has one and only one RecipeMetadata.  It's mapped like so:

```
HasOne(x => x.Metadata);
```

When I run this query, I get the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'NHibernate.QueryException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll
>
> Additional information: could not resolve property: Metadata.SkillCommon of: KitchenPC.DB.Models.Recipes

If I remove the reference to `Metadata`:

```
var q = session.QueryOver<Recipes>(() => recipe)
   //.Where(p => p.Metadata.SkillCommon)
   .Where(p => !p.Hidden);
```

The query works fine.  Not only that, I can see the `Metadata` property under the debugger and I can see the value of `Metadata.SkillCommon`.  So, it is mapped correctly to the database, eagerly loaded (since OneToOne mappings are always eager), and populated with the correct value.  Why in the world can't I do a query on it?

It also has nothing to do with `SkillCommon` (which is a Boolean).  I also can't filter on other properties within `Metadata`, such as numeric values.

Please point out my obviously idiotic error so I can continue on with my evening.  Thanks!

**Update:**

After reading [this article](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/), I'm beginning to think I don't really have a One-To-One mapping.  It *seems* like I do, because a single recipe will always have a single RecipeMetadata row, and no other Recipe will point to that same row, but perhaps this is not the case, since technically two recipes *could* share the same metadata with this schema, I just prevent it from happening through a unique constraint.  Thoughts?

**Update 2:**

I switched to a many-to-one mapping, as suggested by many posts.  In my `Recipes` mapping I now have:

```
References(x => x.Metadata).Column("RecipeId");
```

I can now run the query:

```
var q = session.QueryOver<Recipes>(() => recipe)
   .Fetch(prop => prop.Metadata).Eager()
   .Where(p => !p.Hidden);
```

And the `RecipeMetadata` row is joined in and everything works.  However, *still* when I add:

```
.Where(p => p.Metadata.SkillCommon)
```

I get the same exception as above.  So, this problem had nothing to do with OneToOne mappings.

Comment: I have two questions. First: What happens if you just use `Query<T>`? Second: What happens if you try `QueryOver<Recipes>(() => recipe).JoinQueryOver(r => r.Metadata).Where(r => r.Metadata.SkillCommon)...`.. ?

Comment: I did a test query with `.Query<T>` and when I run it, it issues thousands and thousands of queries.  I think it's doing a `SELECT` against each Metadata row.  I could probably fix that, but using `.Query<T>` would require me to re-write a massive portion of my code.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - `.JoinQueryOver(r => r.Metadata).Where(r => r.SkillCommon)` won't even compile.  The subsequent `Where()` calls now refer to `RecipeMetadata`

Comment: Good point. Didn't think that one through.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Yea before posting my question, I found some other posts hinting at `JoinQueryOver` but I couldn't figure out how to make it work..  I'm really amazed this doesn't just work automatically; it's already doing the JOIN and it has the data it needs.

Comment: What does the other side of this one-to-one look like? Perhaps that part of the mapping is causing the thousands of queries / navigation issue.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - The `RecipeMetadata` model doesn't have any references to anything.  Just mapped fields.  I could probably fix the thousands of queries issue by using a `.Fetch`, but like I said, I can't switch to `.Query<T>` as it doesn't provide the features I need.

Comment: I am wondering if that is the cause though. You would normally map the other side of the relationship too. I.e: `References(x => x.Recipe).Unique();`... in the Metadata mapping.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - You would in a many-to-many mapping, yes.  A One-To-One mapping requires both models to share primary keys.  In other words, `RecipeMetadata` doesn't *have* a `RecipeId` field in the database.

Comment: I added a `HasOne(x => x.Recipe);` to the `RecipeMetadata` model, in essence creating a circular reference, just to see.  It still has not fixed the issue though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45963/discussion-between-simon-whitehead-and-mike-christensen)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Figured it out!  Thanks again for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, though I'm not sure if this is the best and/or only way to do this.  It seems like it should *just work* but sadly, no.

You need to call `.JoinAlias` and explicitly create a `JOIN` against this entity.  You can then refer to that join later on:

```
Models.RecipeMetadata metadata = null;
var q = session.QueryOver<Recipes>(() => recipe)
   .JoinAlias(r => r.Metadata, () => metadata)
   .Where(() => metadata.SkillCommon)
   .Where(p => !p.Hidden);
```

This appears to work great and generate the desired SQL.